# Не отображается мобильная версия сайта

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, mobile-web

Сайт перестал отображаться корректно на мобильных устройствах. На мобильном например хром предлагает адаптировать страницу. Но если перейти на стационарном компе в браузере и уменьшить размер окна- мобильная версия сайта отображается корректно. В чем может быть причина?
Сайт [по этой ссылке](http://firenze.by)

Comment: Да вроде отображается нормально. Только там [ифрейм.наверняка левый](https://rescan.pro/result.php?234146deecedf32a49f2675793c45da1)

Comment: А ещё (допускаю, не факт) гуглохром может ругается из-за закрытых в роботсе скриптов и стилей. Потому как [вот](https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?id=_iK5i8SktSu_KokXRZUBEg)

Comment: Хром отображает, ничего не предлагает. Опишите проблему детально.

Comment: Если раньше отображался нормально, а теперь перестал - что-то случилось. Первый тест - взять дефолтную тему Worpdress и посмотреть, как работает сайт на ней. Если все ОК - значит, проблемы в вашей теме или используемых плагинах. Iframe тянется, скорее всего, с Pluso - сервиса кнопок (он, бывает, сам заражается вирусами). Отключите все плагины по одному и проверьте, осталась ли проблема. В Safari на мобильнике контент шире дисплея. Проверьте CSS на правила @media.

Answer (score 1):

Для точного ответа на вопрос информации недостаточно. Насколько я вижу, наиболее вероятный вариант поломки отображения на мобильных устройствах - использование внешнего сервиса кнопок социальных сетей Pluso.

Как видно из кода страницы в браузере, Pluso подгружает скрипт http://share.pluso.ru/pluso-like.js

Поближе ознакомившись с кодом этого файла (он сжат до одной строки), видим следующее (на данный момент, контент может варьироваться):

```
pluso.tips=[["Распродажа!","Это может быть Вам интересно!","Лучшие товары со скидкой!","Спецпредложения от интернет-магазинов!","Самые продаваемые товары!","Любые товары по лучшим ценам!","Популярные товары по лучшим ценам!","Популярные товары со скидкой!","Товары для комфортной жизни со скидкой!","Самые востребованные товары со скидкой!","Новинки от интернет-магазинов!","Лучшие цены от интернет-магазинов!"
```

Оттуда же тянется iframe http://profile-eu.exe.bid/sandbox/, ссылка на http://memori.ru/ и на https://market.pluso.ru/

Не анализируя долго, в общем можно сказать, что в результате ваш сайт рекламирует совершенно посторонние ресурсы.

Уберите плагин Pluso с сайта, убедитесь, что он действительно удалился, не оставив следов - и, скорее всего, отображение вернется к нормальному.

У вас и так 3 кнопки соцсетей рядом в блоке стоит, зачем еще? Если очень нужны (хотя порой они только вредят продажам), пользуйтесь сервисом Яндекса https://tech.yandex.ru/ или встраивайте самостоятельно.

Ссылка по теме: [поисковый запрос pluso iframe](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=pluso%20iframe).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема была в кривом мета теге, добавленным специально  для яндекс браузера. 
Теперь все отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: Pluso в любом случае стоит убрать - Гугл может пессимизировать выдачу из-за него, случаев много.

Comment: +1 Pluso это давно известный вирус.

Comment: Согласен:) Но заказчик ни в какую не хочет убирать. Никакие аргументы не действуют